# Using JSON to create an email, and uses other list fields in the body of the email

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Currently starting with:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"padding-right": "8px"
},
"txtContent": "@currentField.title"
},
{
"elmType": "a",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "Mail",
"class": "sp-field-quickActions",
"href": {
"operator": "+",
"operands": [
"mailto:",
"@currentField.email",
"?subject=Employee Illness Line Notification status&body=,  The above employee is being monitoring by the Employee Illness line for the following conditions:     They are currently not able to come to work, and have been advised to call in per their unit procedure..\r\n—\r\n",
"@currentField.title",
"[$ID]"
] }
}
}
] }
```

I would like to have the contents of the field named "title" in the test.

"Title" is the name of the person that is ill.  So some text such as `<title>` is out of work due to `<Choice field contents>`.  They will be able to return to work on `<Date field>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON for your person or group column in below format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "8px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "mailto:",
            "@currentField.email",
            "?subject=Employee Illness Line Notification status&body=Hi ",
            "@currentField.title",
            ", ",
            "[$Title]",
            " is out of work due to ",
            "[$ChoiceColumnInternalName]",
            ". They will be able to return to work on ",
            "=toDateString([$DateFieldInternalName])",
            "."
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Use correct internal names for your choice and date column in place of `ChoiceColumnInternalName` and `DateFieldInternalName` respectively.

Follow this article to get the internal name of your SharePoint columns: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with similar questions in  future.